# Detecting client disconnection in tcp

Tags: tcp

I'm writing a server/client application using tcp socket, my problem is how to detect a half-open connection, I was planning to use keep-alive but some suggest me to do my own protocol, so my plan now is:

in the server side:
the server will wait for 10 seconds for the client to send some data, if the server in that given time didn't receive any message from the client, the server will mark the client as disconnected, else, if the the server receive message from client it will reset the timer again.

in the client side:
the client will send message every 10 seconds, but if the server request some data from the client (like if the counter is in 5 seconds, and the client send some data to the server) the timer in client will reset to 0 again.

in short the protocol will count from 0 to 10 after the last message was receive to make the connection closed.

my question now is, is this alright? or im doing it wrong? or is it a bad idea? or will i encounter any problems/error on both the client and server? or will my connection will be blocked by firewall, nat, etc for this method?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a timeout that you can set on the socket, although it is good to implement your own protocol for keep alive. However you don't need to maintain the counter by yourself. Also, you better set the timeout period twice the interval of keep alive, so if your timeout is 10 seconds, you should send the keep alive at least every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

> is this alright?

Yes.

> or im doing it wrong?

Yes. You don't need to maintain your own timer, reset it, etc. Just use `Socket.setSoTimeout().` It will automatically restart from zero every time you call `read()`, and throw a `SocketTimeoutException` if the timeout expires.

> or is it a bad idea?

It's a good idea but you're trying to do your own implementation when `Socket` already supports it.

> or will i encounter any problems/error on both the client and server?

You will encounter `SocketTimeoutException` when the timeout expires when reading, and if this results in you closing the socket, any subsequent sends to the socket will ultimately get an `IOException: connection reset,` which you have to cope with correctly, i.e. by closing the socket at that end and forgetting about that peer.

> or will my connection will be blocked by firewall, nat, etc for this method?

Using read timeouts has no additional effects on firewalls or NAT.

Comment: thx for the answers, i got another question, if i used this kind of way to detect client disconnection, will it stress out the server/used lots of resources if i have many clients?